# PostgreSQL won't do inner join with primary key

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query:

```
SELECT id, year, avg(amount) from table1
WHERE amount IS NOT NULL
INNER JOIN table2
ON table1.id = table2.id
GROUP BY id
```

2 Issues:

1. This only works if I remove the Where amount is not null, and
2. I remove the 'id' from SELECT and GROUP BY

I can group by year, but It won't let me put the primary key "id" in my select statement and also group on it. Any suggestions?

In general, I'd like to get the avg amount for each id for each year and then join it with another table with id, but I want id in my returned query.

Comment: What is your WHERE clause doing up there in your FROM clause. It's like a crazy persons query.

Comment: ID will be a field in both table1 and tables 2, so you need to qualify which one you want (select table1.id, etc...).  Year is not in your group by and will need to be.  and your where clause is in a silly spot.  where after join ;)

Comment: Yes, I don't need the WHERE, but some of my amounts have null values. I can group by year, but not id

Comment: your syntax is wrong - see answers below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to qualify the 'id' column as it is present in 2 tables in your query.

```
SELECT table1.id, year, avg(amount) from table1
INNER JOIN table2
ON table1.id = table2.id
WHERE amount IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY table1.id, year
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT id, year,  avg(amount) over(partition by year, order by id) from table1
INNER JOIN table2
ON table1.id = table2.id
WHERE amount IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY id, year
```

Comment: Yes I have tried this, but I still get an error on the SELECT id. It  only works if I don't select or group by id, but that returns me an avg per year, not id

Comment: BTW you have to qualify the fields that exist in both tables as others have mentioned - so id in the select should be table1.id etc

Comment: Thanks! That was the issue. I wasn't specifying my table name for each id and so it was ambiguous. I didn't end up needing the partiion though.

Answer (score 1):

You've got a lot of things going haywire here. Properly written your query should look something like:

```
SELECT table1.id, table1.year, avg(table2.amount) 
FROM table1
    INNER JOIN table2
        ON table1.id = table2.id
WHERE amount IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY table1.id, year;
```

1. WHERE clause is separate from the `FROM` clause. They don't get combined.
2. Your fields have their full path with the table name so your DB knows which `id` you want in the output
3. All non-aggregated fields are present in your GROUP BY. Only older version of MySQL allow you to leave them out, and even then it produces nonsense and confusion.

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax is:

```
SELECT id, year, avg(amount) 
FROM table1 JOIN
     table2
     ON table1.id = table2.id
WHERE amount IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY id, year;
```

`WHERE` is a clause that follows the `FROM` clause.  `JOIN` is an *operator* that works only in the `FROM` clause.  You will note that when I indent queries, the clauses are left justified, and the binary operators are at the end of line.

Answer (score 0):

You should include also the where condition in ON clause

```
  SELECT id, year, avg(amount) from table1

  INNER JOIN table2
  ON table1.id = table2.id and  amount IS NOT NULL
  GROUP BY id, year
```

*and add year to group by too*